# init.d startup script

Tags: command-line, server, bash, scripts, init.d

I try to create a init.d service script for the glassfish software.
But it seems like my understandings in the LSB init.d guidelines are not the best.

This are the commmands the script should do:

```
/opt/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain
/opt/glassfish/bin/asadmin stop-domain
/opt/glassfish/bin/asadmin restart-domain
```

My script looks like this but it didn't work. This is my first try to make a init.d script. Please tell me when I do something wrong.

Note: Please look my updated script below EDIT:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
#
# Provides:     glassfish
# Required-Start:   $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:    2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:     0 1 6
# Short-Description:    Glassfish scipt (Non official)
# Description:  Start Glassfish domain as service.
#       Non official startup script.
#
### END INIT INFO

BASE=/opt/glassfish/bin
DEAMON=${BASE}/asadmin
USERID=root
NAME=glassfish
DESC="Glassfish domain service"
# PID file for the deamon
PIDFILE=/var/run/glassfish.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DEAMON" ] || exit 0

# Using LSB functions to perform the operations
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start()
{
    start-stop-deamon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DEAMON start-domain -- $NAME_OPTIONS
}

do_stop()
{
    start-stop-deamon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DEAMON stop-domain
}

case $1 in
    start)
        if init_is_upstart; then
            exit 1
        fi
        log_deamon_msg "Starting $DESC"
        do_start
        case "$?" in
            0) sendsigs_omit 
               log_end_msg 0 ;;
            1) log_progress_msg "already started"
               log_end_msg 0 ;;
            *) log_end_msg 1 ;;
        esac

        ;;
    stop)
        if init_is_upstart; then
            exit 0
        fi
        log_deamon_msg "Stopping $DESC"
        do_stop
        case "$?" in
            0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
            1) log_progress_msg "already stopped"
               log_end_msg 0 ;;
            *) log_emd_msg 1 ;;
        esac

        ;;
    restart|force-reload)
        if init_is_upstart; then
            exit 1
        fi
        $0 stop
        $0 start
        ;;
    status)
        status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE $DEAMON && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|restart|status}" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac

:
```

When I do a '/bin/bash -x ./glassfish status' this is the output:

```
+ case "$FANCYTTY" in
+ true
++ /usr/bin/tput setaf 1
+ RED=''
++ /usr/bin/tput op
+ NORMAL=''
+ echo ' *  is not running'
 *  is not running
+ return 3
+ exit 3
```

But it doesn't matter if I do a start or stop. The result is always the same. The script doesn't start the glassfish domain server.
Without script everything works fine.

EDIT:

I changed the script to this:

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
#
# Provides:     glassfish
# Required-Start:   $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:    2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:     0 1 6
# Short-Description:    Glassfish scipt (Non official)
# Description:  Start Glassfish domain as service.
#       Non official startup script
#
### END INIT INFO

# Using the LSB functions to perform the operations
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

BASE=/opt/glassfish/bin
NAME=glassfish
DAEMON=${BASE}/asadmin
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

#PID file for the daemon
PIDFILE=/var/run/glassfish.pid

#If the daemon is not there, then exit
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 5

do_start()
{
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON start-domain
}

do_stop()
{
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE
}

case $1 in
    start)
        #Check PID file
        if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
            status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON "$NAME process" && status="0" || status="$?"
            # IF SUCCESS dont start again
            if [ $status = "0" ]; then
                exit
            fi
        fi

        #Start the daemon
        log_daemon_msg "Starting the process" "$NAME"
        if do_start; then
            log_end_msg 0
        else
            log_end_msg 1
        fi
        ;;

    stop)
        # Stop the daemon
        if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
            status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON "Stopping the $NAME process" && status="0" || status="$?"
            if [ "$status" = 0]; then
                do_stop
            fi
        else
            log_daemon_msg "$NAME process is not running"
            log_end_msg 0
        fi
        ;;

    restart)
        # Restart the daemon
            $0 stop && sleep 2 && $0 start
        ;;

    status)
        # Check status
        if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
            status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON "$NAME process" && exit 0 || exit $?
        else
            log_daemon_msg "$NAME Process is not running"
            log_end_msg 0
        fi
        ;;

    *)
        # Show help
        echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|restart}" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac
```

After the change the output is this:

```
 * Starting the process glassfish                                                                                                                                                                                                            Waiting for domain1 to start .........
Successfully started the domain : domain1
domain  Location: /opt/glassfish/domains/domain1
Log File: /opt/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log
Admin Port: 4848
Command start-domain executed successfully.
```

It can start the process now. Then the next problem appears when stopping the service:

```
 * glassfish process is not running
```

But the process is running and the script does not even try and just abort. There is also no glassfish PID file under /var/run.

Comment: Is there anything interesting in `/var/log/upstart/glassfish*` or thereabouts?

Comment: Status) and *) are working.

Comment: No there is no glassfish file.

Comment: And no 'glassfish.pid' file under '/var/run/'.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I am using Xubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I used the wrong word. It must be 'daemon' not 'deamon'. I will rewrite then testing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I get it working!

If someones interested in the answer. The problem is that the Glassfish didn't create a PID file by itself. So there is a workaround needed where you start the program in the background (with &) and output its PID.

For the understanding I looked this posts:

Patrick's answer

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137519/start-stop-daemon-not-working-as-expected-no-pid-file-was-written

l0b0's answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890062/how-to-run-a-program-and-know-its-pid-in-linux

kojiro's answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollar-sign-shell-variables

Stack*(askUbuntu)-community is really a great community! :)

And here is the full working script:

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
#
# Provides:     glassfish
# Required-Start:   $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:    2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:     0 1 6
# Short-Description:    Glassfish scipt (Non official)
# Description:  Start Glassfish domain as service.
#       Non official startup script by Bernhard Sumser.
#
### END INIT INFO

# Using the LSB functions to perform the operations
# NOT needed because no LSB functions used
#. /lib/lsb/init-functions

BASE=/opt/glassfish/bin
NAME=glassfish
DAEMON=${BASE}/asadmin
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

#PID file for the daemon
PIDFILE=/var/run/glassfish.pid

#If the DAEMON is not there, then exit
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0


do_start()
{
    $DAEMON start-domain &
    # Wait for child to exit before continuing
    wait
    # Make file with last background PID
    echo $! > $PIDFILE

    # Didn't work because the programm prints from the background. Without moving to the bg no $! can be outputed to file
    #(($DAEMON start-domain) & echo $! > $PIDFILE &)
}

do_stop()
{
    $DAEMON stop-domain
    if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
        rm -f $PIDFILE
    fi
}

check_root()
{
    if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
        echo "You must be root to start, stop and restart $NAME."
        exit 4
    fi
}

check_process()
{
    # Check if the process is already running. Ignore grep line.
    result=`ps aux | grep /opt/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar | grep -v grep | wc -l`
}

case $1 in
    start)
        check_root
        check_process
        if [ "$result" = "1"  ]; then
            echo "$NAME is already running"
        else
            # Check if PID file exists and delete it
            if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
                rm -f $PIDFILE
            else
                do_start
            fi              
        fi
    ;;

    stop)
        check_root
        if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
            do_stop
        else
            echo "$NAME is not running"
        fi
    ;;

    restart)
        check_root
        echo "Restarting $NAME..."
        check_process
        if [ "$result" = "1"  ]; then
            do_stop
            echo "Starting $NAME..."
            do_start
        fi                  
    ;;

    status)
        if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
            echo "$NAME is running. PID $(cat $PIDFILE)"
        else
            echo "$NAME is not running"
        fi
    ;;


    *)
            # Show help
            echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|status|stop|restart}" >&2
            exit 3
    ;;
esac
```

Since it is located under /etc/init.d/ I am not sure if the script still needs the INIT INFO section.

Now it is possible to use it as normal service like this:

```
sudo service glassfish start
```

Then add it to the rc startup and it will start after reboot.

```
sudo update-rc.d glassfish defaults
```